# How to specify a binary to use some specific dll files?

Tags: dll, winsxs

We are developing audio plugins which are dynamic libraries. This made it very hard to use 3rd-party libraries such as Qt, as our product DLL would search for Qt's DLL on host DAW program's executable directory, and it is impossible to install our dependent DLLs to that position (you don't know which host will be used, and host may even be installed later than the plugin).

I've made some brief search on this problem, the few answers direct me to a Microsoft technology called *side-by-side assembly*, and I'm almost drawn in the huge documentation and concepts on that. So my question is:

- How to make my DLL to load several specific dependent DLLs located at `path_to_plugin/MyPlugin_dependents/xxx.dll`?
- Or is there any examples to *side-by-side assembly* that simply do this and is much simpler than the official example?

Comment: Side-by-side is only for DLLs which implement COM classes/interfaces, as far as I know. Does that apply to what you are doing?

Comment: @StayOnTarget Nope, I'm not working with any COM things.